# Will you lose games you got with xbox game pass ultimate?

Tags: forza-horizon-4, xbox-game-pass

I am thinking about cancelling my xbox game pass ultimate subscription. I have Forza Horizon 4 which was included with the pass. If I cancel now, will I have to pay for the game to keep playing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your game pass is up you will have to buy the game to continue playing. All of your game data will still be there if you do purchase the game so you can pick up where you left off.